# Multitenancy and Code Repetition - How to avoid conditional overload by "composing" logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, multi-tenant

I have a multitenant application with very few tenants and minor customization needed per tenant.

I'm finding that a lot of our codebase contains logic like the following:

```
public async Task<Banana> PeelBanana(Banana banana)
    {
        if (_tenant == Tenant.A){
           NotifyMonkey();
        } else if (_tenant == Tenant.B){
           GetCoconut();
        }
        banana.FinishPeeling();
        return banana;
    }
```

Is there some kind of pattern that addresses this scenario, where I have a need to *compose* my logic based on some criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the organization of the other code, you could use something like:

```
public async Task<Banana> PeelBanana(Banana banana)
{
    _tenant.OnPeelBanana(banana);
    banana.FinishPeeling();
    return banana;
}
```

and use different sub-types of the `Tenant` class. But of course that depends on that functions like `NotifyMonkey` could be moved there or are accessible from there.